# Get-eventlog: How to get all Logs (Application, System, Security, etc) using powershell

Tags: powershell, get-eventlog

I am trying to read All log files from EventLog using Get-eventlog commandlet

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application, Security -after 09/15/2016 -Before 09/17/2016
```

Instead of -LogName Application, I need all logs like Application, System, Security, etc.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

You can get all the event logs like this:

```
(Get-WinEvent –ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LogName
```

And then either do a loop across them to get events from each of the logs, or try to pass entire array as `-LogName`, but I can imaging that performance penalty will be huge in this case.

Also, [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent) was developed to replace the `Get-EventLog`, so you might want to use it instead. Here's some info: http://blog.netwrix.com/2015/04/06/monitoring-event-logs-with-powershell/

Comment: There's a 256 number of logname's limit in the windows api.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code based on @andrey-marchuk's answer. All the log are appended in a single file( ⚠ save the file with encoding `UTF-8 with BOM` because of the `@`)

```
$Begin = '10/02/2022 09:00:00'
$End = '10/02/2022 09:15:05'
$path= "C:\Users\user\Desktop\logevent\\"
If(!(test-path $path))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
$datetimenow =  [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd HH_mm_ss")
$allLog = (Get-WinEvent –ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LogName
foreach ($lognameName in $allLog){
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname = $lognameName; StartTime = "$Begin"; EndTime = "$End" }  | Select-Object * | Out-File -Enc UTF8 -Append "$path $datetimenow winevent.txt"
}
```

If you want to retrieve only specific info of the events, then replace `Select-Object *` by something like `Select-Object TimeCreated, ID, LogName, Source, LevelDisplayName, Message`

---

If you want separate files for each `logname`, you can do this, but be carefully, this will create > 400 files:

```
$Begin = '10/02/2022 09:00:00'
$End = '10/02/2022 09:15:05'
$path= "C:\Users\user\Desktop\logevent\\"
If(!(test-path $path))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
$allLog = (Get-WinEvent –ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LogName

foreach ($lognameName in $allLog){
$lognameFile = $lognameName.Replace("/", "-")
$datetimenow =  [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd HH_mm_ss")
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname = $lognameName; StartTime = "$Begin"; EndTime = "$End" }  | Select-Object * | Out-File -Enc UTF8 -FilePath "$path $datetimenow winevent $lognameFile .txt"

}
```